# How to use CURL over SSH and get the file as well as the return value?

Tags: bash, curl, ssh

I want to load a file from a clients webserver. This webserver is running local only. To get there I have to use ssh. I need the content as well as the return value (e.g. SSH connection broke, webserver down).

What do I have to change? My first try:

```
#!/bin/bash

RETURN=0
CONTENT=""

sshpass -p xxxxxx ssh root@172.17.1.33 "curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:10000/status -H 'Content-Type: application/json' > $CONTENT | bash; RETURN=$?"
```

Comment: The exit status of `ssh` will be the exit status of `curl` if that's the only command you run. `sshpass` doesn't allow you to retrieve the exit status of `ssh`, which is another reason to set up public-key authentication instead of using `sshpass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the exit code of `curl` and the return value of `curl`:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTENT=$(sshpass -p xxxxxx ssh root@172.17.1.33 "curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:10000/status -H 'Content-Type: application/json'")

RETURN=$?

echo "$RETURN, $CONTENT"
```

In your script you set the variables on the server you ssh'ed into.

Comment: Almost there. When I do this, `$CONTENT` shows a mixture in a single line of the multiline-output of the servers output. Why is that?

Comment: Whats the actual output and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: 8 lines of json output

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to put double quotes around `"$CONTENT"` or maybe the value contains DOS carriage returns.